# Standard Screencast does not work

Tags: 20.10, screencast

After updating to 20.10, the standard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) system screen cast to file stopped working. Files do not appear, the red flag in the tray does not appear. How fix it ?